# Glassfish JMS queue with HornetQ: Store locally and Forward remotely

Tags: glassfish, jms, hornetq

I need some precise steps (with reference to glassfish docs) for the following scenario;

- How to create JMS queues to support "store locally and forward remotely". The remote system is HornetQ.
- The remote connectivity should support SSL and user/password authentication
- It should support automatic retry and configuration of # of retry.
- In case of any failure, it should be possible to select the jms messages are resend in bulk

I already went through some of the glassfish docs but needs to be further validated by the experts.

Simple Scenario but still not working "Send a JMS to sourceQueue and JMS bridge service to transfer to targetQueue". Here are the configurations;

A. domain.xml (extract)

```
<jms-service default-jms-host="default_JMS_host" type="EMBEDDED">
    <jms-host host="localhost" name="default_JMS_host" lazy-init="false">
      <property name="imq.bridge.bridge1.type" value="jms"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.bridge1.xmlurl" value="file:///C:/TEMP/bridge.xml"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.bridge1.autostart" value="true"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.bridge1.logfile.limit" value="0"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.bridge1.logfile.count" value="1"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.enabled" value="true"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.admin.user" value="admin"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.admin.password" value="admin"></property>
      <property name="imq.bridge.activelist" value="bridge1"></property>
    </jms-host>
</jms-service>
```

B. bridge.xml (bridge configuration)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jmsbridge SYSTEM "sun_jmsbridge_1_0.dtd">
<jmsbridge name="bridge1">
    <link name="link1">
        <enabled ="true"></enabled>
           <source connection-factory-ref=”jms/__defaultConnectionFactory" destination-ref="sourceQueue"></source>
     <target connection-factory-ref="jms/__defaultConnectionFactory" destination-ref="targetQueue "></target>
    </link>
    <connection-factory ref-name="jms/__defaultConnectionFactory"/>
    <connection-factory ref-name="jms/__defaultConnectionFactory"/>
    <destination ref-name="sourceQueue" type="queue" lookup-name="sourceQueue"/>
    <destination ref-name="targetQueue" type="queue" lookup-name="targetQueue"/>
</jmsbridge>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish deploys the Glassfish JMS server. If you want to talk to HornetQ you need to use HornetQ libraries and use the proper API (either core or JMS) to talk to the HornetQ server.

If you need XA integration through MDBs then you will need to deploy the Resource Adapter and do the proper recovery integration. Look at the glassFish on how to deploy an external resource adapter.. but that's an area that nobody at RedHat has tested yet and given the state of glassFish being discontinued I doubt that will happen any time soon.

Another way you could do is to deploy the JMS Bridge within JBoss / HornetQ, Where any message sent on GlassFish JMS would be consumed on HornetQ through the bridging process.

Comment: Thanks; have you or someone in the forum created any successful example of JMS Bridge in Glassfish? If so, please share the configuration file along with XML JM Bridge file?

Comment: It's a pretty standard thing. Just look at our JMS Bridge examples. You just need glassfish libraries.. and you do it on the jboss side.
It seems I have answered your question.. I would appreciate you accepting it.

Comment: Hi Clebert,
Yes, its pretty standard I am wondering why JMS Bridge is not working. I created a simplest scenario; Send msg to sourceQueue, JMS Bridge to transfer messages to a targetQueue. All locally with in MQ + Glassfish. I embedded the domain.xml and bridge.xml in the original message. Can you kind have a look and advise if I am missing something for this basic and standard configuration. Also I am getting an error on JMS Bridge Service "Error while performing this operation on the broker.
[B2215]: Bridge service manager is not running

Comment: You should open an user's forum on HornetQ so we can look at what you did wrong. from the POV of StackOverFlow the question is answered and I can't review configurations here.. SOF is not a place for conversations.. etc.. if you open an user's forum with some config post we can help you.
https://community.jboss.org/en/hornetq?view=discussions